# Clarity on proof on compact subset of hausdorff space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $F$ be a compact subset of Hausdorff space $X$ and $x\in X-F$, then there exists disjoint open sets $U, V$ such that $F\subset U$ and $x \subset V$.

I do have a correct version of the proof which I understand, but I need some clarity on why the proof I came up with wouldn't work since I don't see any problem with it.

Proof: Let $y\in F$, then since we are in a Hausdorff space there exist disjoint open sets $U_y, U_x$ that contain $y,x$ respectively. Now, define $U=\cup_{y \in F} U_y$. We have U is an arbitrary union of open sets, so $U$ is open in $X$, also $F \subset U$, and since each $y$ we have $U_y \cap U_x =\emptyset$, then $U$ and $U_x$ must be disjoint. Hence completing the proof.

Thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use different capital letters for the two disjoint open sets you begin with. And your "$U_x$" does not depend on $x$ but on $y$. So: better call it $V_y.$

Then, once you noticed that $F\subset U$, you shoud use $F$'s compacity (you used it nowhere!) to extract from $(U_y)_{y\in F}$ a finite subcover $(U_{y_1},\dots,U_{y_n})$.

Finally, $U_{y_k}\cap V_{y_k}=\varnothing\not\Rightarrow U\cap V_{y_k}=\varnothing.$

Answer (score 2):

Note that the $U_x$ you choose depends on $y$; $x$ itself is fixed in your problem. Hence your first line should read: For each $y \in F$, since $X$ is Hausdorff, there exist disjoint open sets $U_y$ and $V_y$ containing $y$ and $x$ respectively.

What it seems you are doing is assuming something much stronger, that there is an open set $U_x$ containing $x$ such that for **every** $y \in F$, there exists an open set $U_y$ disjoint from $U_x$ and containing $y$. To find such a $U_x$, the natural thing to do here is to use the $V_y$'s mentioned above and take $U_x = \cap_{y \in F} V_y$; unfortunately this is not guaranteed to be open, since this an arbitrary intersection of open sets, and not necessarily a finite one.

Note your proof did not use the assumption that $F$ is compact; can you see where to use it now?